# Getting 4k working on Haswell graphics for AOC U2868PQU

Tags: graphics, 14.10

I am setting up an AOC U2868PQU 4k monitor and I can't get it to work as 4k, only as 1080p.

It should run 4k over DisplayPort (DP) 1.2. If I connect just the DP, I get a blank screen; if I plug both VGA and DP in, I can use the screen via VGA. However if I lower the resolution for the 4k screen to 1080 or less, it works via DP.

Under Display Settings, I can see the screen recognized from both sources, however it will not actually use the DP source: when I click on it, it doesn't change the screen. Just now, when I clicked and then hit "Apply", the PC crashed and I got an error report.

It recognizes two screens, as I can plug a second monitor into the VGA, which works fine. Then if I mirror displays, or if I choose any resolution up to 1080, both screens work. Still no 4k, tho.

In xrandr, I get the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 621mm x 341mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 connected primary 3840x2160+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 621mm x 341mm
   3840x2160      60.0*+   30.0     30.0     25.0     24.0     30.0     24.0  
   1920x1080      60.0     60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

As you can see, the DP2 is set as primary, but still not showing anything.

I'm running stock Ubuntu 14.10 on a Lenovo Thinkcentre desktop, and a Haswell  i5-4670 CPU with the integrated Intel HD Graphics 4600, no graphics card.

Comment: you shouldn't take this personally.  It's just that a question with an answer "Naah, id was a dodgy cable" is deemed "off topic" on a site that is all about software.  The same happened to me when I told someone to vacuum clean his computer. 100% correct, 100% useful, but not a software solution...  ;-)

Comment: Sure, I don't take it personally, so that's up to you who know more than I do about the site. Only thing is, i spent considerable time researching to find an answer, and consulted with 4 IT experts, to no avail. Almost all discussion of getting 4k working dealt with GPUs, so I couldn't find any info on using 4k with the integrated graphics alone. As it happens, basically it was plug and play, which is perhaps something that might be useful to someone else...

Comment: I personally agree with you, but I'm just the messenger. I'm too low-level to even know whether your question is still going to remain here for future reference.  IMHO, 80% of all IT problems can be brought back to dodgy cables and bad drivers...  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Solved: the problem was the cable, new cable, no problems.